# Value of "size" from StatisticsPlugin always 0

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.15.11, and I am trying to get the number of pending messages programatically using the [StatisticsPlugin](http://activemq.apache.org/statisticsplugin.html) plugin.

Below is the code used to create & send the message to `ActiveMQ.Statistics.Broker`:

```java
public void produceMessage(String queueName, String message, boolean replyToTempQueue) throws JMSException {
    
    // Create a connection factory.
    final ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
        new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(System.getenv("WIRE_LEVEL_ENDPOINT"));

    // Pass the username and password.
    connectionFactory.setUserName(System.getenv("ACTIVE_MQ_USERNAME"));
    connectionFactory.setPassword(System.getenv("ACTIVE_MQ_PASSWORD"));

    // Create a pooled connection factory.
    final PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory = new PooledConnectionFactory();
    pooledConnectionFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    pooledConnectionFactory.setMaxConnections(10);

    // Establish a connection for the producer.
    final Connection producerConnection = pooledConnectionFactory.createConnection();
    producerConnection.start();
    
    // Create a session.
    final Session producerSession = producerConnection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    // Create a queue named "MyQueue".
    final ActiveMQQueue producerDestination = (ActiveMQQueue) producerSession.createQueue(queueName);

    // Create a producer from the session to the queue.
    final MessageProducer producer = producerSession.createProducer(producerDestination);
    producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
    
    // Create a message.
    Message producerMessage = null;
    
    // Add a reply to queue if one has been provided.
    if (replyToTempQueue) {
      producerMessage = producerSession.createMapMessage();
      producerMessage.setJMSReplyTo(producerSession.createTemporaryQueue());
    } else {
      producerMessage = producerSession.createTextMessage(message);
    }
    
    // Send the message.
    producer.send(producerMessage);
    System.out.println("Message sent.");
    producer.close();
    producerSession.close();
    producerConnection.close();
  }
```

However, it is always showing a size of 0. Why is this?

```
ActiveMQMapMessage {commandId = 6, responseRequired = false, messageId = ID:DESKTOP-CQNTDSL-64043-1583929718154-177:1:1:1:1, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:DESKTOP-CQNTDSL-64043-1583929718154-177:1:1:1, destination = queue://ActiveMQ.Statistics.Broker, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 1583946785436, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1583946785552, brokerOutTime = 1583946785811, correlationId = null, replyTo = temp-queue://ID:DESKTOP-CQNTDSL-64043-1583929718154-177:1:1, persistent = false, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = null, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = null, readOnlyProperties = true, readOnlyBody = true, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false} ActiveMQMapMessage{ theTable = {} }
```

Comment: Just added it now

Comment: What makes you think the internal size value of the message would be anything other than zero in this case?

Comment: @JustinBertram the queueName is ActiveMQ.Statistics.Broker, the message is a string made up of who the email is to, from, its subject and body. This is done through through a request mapping

Comment: @TimBish I have been using the ActiveMQ message broker to look at the length of the queue

Comment: @JustinBertram ApacheMQ 5, which I believe is the latest

Comment: @JustinBertram Version 5.15.11

Answer (score 0):

The `size` you're looking at doesn't indicate the number of pending messages in the broker. You need to inspect the `enqueueCount` value instead of `size`. According to [the docs](http://activemq.apache.org/statisticsplugin.html) this value is returned when querying `ActiveMQ.Statistics.Broker`.

You can also get this data for a specific destination by querying `ActiveMQ.Statistics.Destination`. From [the docs](http://activemq.apache.org/statisticsplugin.html):

> ...to query the statistics for a destination just send a message to the destination name prepended with `ActiveMQ.Statistics.Destination`. For example, to retrieve the statistics for a queue whose name is `TEST.FOO`, send an empty message to the queue named `ActiveMQ.Statistics.Destination.TEST.FOO`...

Comment: How do I go about looking at the enqueueCount? And I have already been sending a message with that value prepended

Comment: You've been sending a message with *what* value prepended? Are you talking about `ActiveMQ.Statistics.Destination`? In the comment above you said you were sending the message to `ActiveMQ.Statistics.Broker`.

Comment: You look at `enqueueCount` the same way you look at `size` - via the returned `MapMessage`.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, I have tried it with lots of different values, including ActiveMQ.Statistics.Destination."QueueName". It doesn't seem to be returning an enqueueCount value

Comment: Can you provide what it actually returns?

Comment: I have provided it in the original question

Comment: The information you provided in the original question was the reply you got when you sent a message to `ActiveMQ.Statistics.Broker`. I'm asking for the reply you get when you send a message to `ActiveMQ.Statistics.Destination.QueueName`. **These are 2 different destinations**.

Comment: It returns the same values

Comment: I updated my answer. After reviewing the docs more carefully I see that `enqueueCount` is supposed to be returned when querying either `ActiveMQ.Statistics.Broker` or `ActiveMQ.Statistics.Destination`. That said, I don't see it in the response you posed in your original question. This may be a bug in the StatisticsPlugin.